# Minimal property of a graph.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, terminology

A graph $G$ is said to be ***minimal*** if it loses property $P$
after deletion of an arbitrary edge.

I am considering a graph $G$ with edges $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ with property $P$.
It loses its property only after deletion of edges $e_2$ and $e_n$.
However, it retains property $P$ if we delete other edges $e_1,e_3,\ldots,e_{n-1}$.
Can I say that graph $G$ is minimal? I am quite confused here. Kindly help.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: This may depend on the property $P$ you are talking about. In most cases I would expect that minimal means deleting any edge destroys property $P$.

Comment: @quarague That is the confusion actually. What if I choose to delete edge $e_1$ and you choose to delete $e_2$?

Answer (score 5):

You are defining minimal as follows:

> A graph G is said to be minimal if it loses property P after deletion of **an arbitrary** edge.

Now since in the graph you consider the property is retained after deleting of $e_1$, so your graph is not minimal. It would have been minimal if you couldn't find an edge whose removal retains the property.